# rotating MKMapView

Tags: ios, ios5, mkmapview, uiinterfaceorientation

I have a working app with an MKMapView showing user location. So far, so good:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   ...
   [myMapView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
   [myMapView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollow animated:YES];
}
```

Now, I allow interface rotations:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations.
    return YES;
}
```

If I now turn the device and center to the user location

```
   [myMapView setCenterCoordinate:[myMapView userLocation].coordinate animated:YES];
```

The mapView will rotate as expected, but the user location will not be centered, but on the bottom of the screen (distance from top stays the same as in portrait mode).

I expect it to be centered, though...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try including height in the `setAutoresizingMask:` so that the map view's height will automatically change when the superview changes its height on rotation.  Right now, only the width is resizing and so the y position of the map's center doesn't change.

So this line:

```
[myMapView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
```

should be:

```
[myMapView setAutoresizingMask: 
    (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight)];
```

Additionally, you shouldn't need to manually center the map on the user location if you are setting the tracking mode to `MKUserTrackingModeFollow` (the map will do it automatically).  You may have tried manually centering it to fix the height issue but fixing the autoresizing mask should eliminate the need for the explicit centering.

Comment: Ok Thanks - should have read the flag name until it's end :) And concerning the centering: I actually center for different points, not only the user location depending on the user input. But thanks for pointing this out...