# How to rotate the google map according to the device?

Tags: ios, google-maps

I am writing a google map based app, I add a uiview to display the map view. When the screen is vertical, it is all right. But when I rotate, the map  view can not display completely. 
[image]

What is wrong here with the auto layout ?

This is my viewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self authenticateAndRequestLocation];

    map = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:self.view.bounds camera:camera];

    [self.mapView addSubview:map];
```

Comment: What are your constraints on your layout?

Comment: Trailling space, leading space and top space to Superview, bottom to bottom layout guide.

Comment: What about the "marker" on the right? Make sure that the MapView is the only thing in the view and verify that it isn't rotating. It could be the marker blocking the rotation.

Comment: The marker is a UIbutton.

Comment: It is the same when I delete the button.

Comment: Xie I can't verify right now, but this seems like a good idea.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865945/rotating-mkmapview

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103154/discussion-between-xie-and-patrick-zawadzki).

Comment: Sorry, it does work. Thank you anyway.

Comment: No problem. You got the solution working then?